# Spree error 500 

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, webrick, spree, slicehost

Need some help here.

I have deployed spree (0.70.3) on slicehost (ubuntu, ruby1.8.7, Rails
3.1.3), installed the spree gem, loaded in the sample data
successfully following the steps on spree startup manual and I am
using passenger (it works on localhost:3000). When I upload to my
server, however, instead of seeing the spree interface, I am getting
an error message. From the production.log:

> Processing by HomeController#index as HTML Completed 500 Internal
>   Server Error in 22ms ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Could not find
>   table 'product_groups'):

Any suggestions how I can get this to work?

Website: http://www.nutxboutique.com

Comment: I have already added "AllowOverride all" and "Options -MultiViews" to my virtual host configuration <directory> settings to relax apache security settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

production.log is the rails log.  It appears your problem is occurring before rails completes loading.  If you're using apache, check/post the apache logs, it might have more clues as to what's going on.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I forgot to grant 666 permission to production.log, that was why it was empty. Now it correctly records the error: Started GET "/" for 123.125.71.99 at Mon Jan 16 07:44:25 +0000 2012
  Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 22ms

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Could not find table 'product_groups'):

Comment: This looks to me like you've not run the migrations on your production environment's database. You'll need to do that.

Comment: Thanks @RyanBigg for your reply. I followed the guide at http://guides.spreecommerce.com/getting_started.html and ran (1)sudo rails g spree:site (2)sudo rake db:bootstrap (which consists of migrate, seed, load sample data and create admin)...is that all I need to run?

Comment: That would set it up in in the development environment. You would need to run `rake db:bootstrap` (with NO sudo) like this: `rake db:bootstrap RAILS_ENV=production`.